# Nuxt/Axios - can't display array from database correctly on page

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

**UPDATE (July 18th):** I have made changes according to the help i have recieved in this thread, and have updated the payload and the problem I am facing.

I am pretty new with Nuxt and Axios and I am having big difficulties in displaying a list of simple data from an array from the database. As of now, I am only getting a blank screen.
But if I change `{{ user.firstName }} - {{ user.email }}` to `{{ users }}` instead in my Vue-page (pages/matches.vue), this is what is being displayed on the page in an almost infinite number of times:

```
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]
```

What I want is to display, is each users 'firstName' and 'email' per line.

Here is my code:

pages/matches.vue

```
<template>
    <section class="container mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8  py-3">

        <div class="container w-full flex flex-wrap mx-auto px-12 pt-4 lg:pt-2 mt-6 ">
            <section class="w-full lg:w-4/5">
            <div id="app-4">
                <ol>
                    <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
                        {{ user.firstName }} - {{ user.email }}
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <!--divider-->
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$axios
        .get('/api/users/all')
        .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err;
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
// Get all Users
router.get(
    '/api/users/all', 
    UserController.getAll // Log in the User using the UserController (controllers/User.js)
)
```

controllers/User.js

```
// Find all users
exports.getAll  = async (req, res) => {
    let users = await models.User.findAll();
    let allUsers = JSON.stringify(users);
    res.json(allUsers);
}
```

If I console.log `allUsers` this is what I am getting:

```
[
{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},
{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}
]
```

Can any of you see what the problem could be?

Comment: You can filter data from JSON that you are getting just by doing user.response.data.id I think. if you are getting the expected response from your API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
mounted() {
    this.$axios
    .get('/api/users/all')
    .then(response => {
        this.users = response.data;
      
        return response.data;
        // console.log("HERE : " + this.users);
        
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
}
```

Point is skipping the `JSON.stringify` part and get the exact user array from the response. After that, in the HTML code,

```
<li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
   {{ user.firstName }}  {{ user.email }} <!-- Depending on how the users are structured in the model -->
</li>
```

Comment: Let me know the results. If not satisfactory, with proper errors from the console may be I can edit and improve this answer further.

Comment: Thank you @TahmidAli for you help. After trying your code, I am not getting anything displaying on the Page, and I am not getting any errors in the Console.
In the terminal I am getting this:

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `password`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `age`, `gender`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User`;

Comment: **UPDATE:** when I change `{{ user.firstName }}` back to `{{ users }}` I get a long list with the users displayed in JSON format multiple times.

Comment: @RicoRos, can you please copy paste the output of {{users}}..? that way I could get some insights of how the json data is structured. Also try to put console.log(allUsers)  in the API just before writing the response. We can check by skipping json.stringify here as well.

Comment: Hi @TahmidAli - when use {{ users }} i get this displayed infinte on my page:
[{"id":1,"email":"rico.rosenkrans@inovium.dk","password":"$2a$10$d1G/b9CRfoOxqihzrrG18uYqFgwM91VcJbJPHoBZzY8EGKFgjoFUC","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":35,"gender":"Mand","createdAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T20:53:14.000Z"},{"id":2,"email":"test@test.dk","password":"$2a$10$GnKUl5vA0n9ds4X.WGOc9e..XjVeJQJaY7/39UyusDWo7dBCx3jVK","firstName":"Rico","lastName":"Rosenkrans","age":32,"gender":"Kvinde","createdAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-07-16T23:37:16.000Z"}]

Comment: I am not sure why, but when I tried removing ```JSON.stringify```once more, it worked!! Sooo nice - thank you!